# Upper case letter followed by lower case letter in a string

Tags: python, string, search, sequence

How to check if string has a letter sequence of 1 upper, followed by 1 lower and so on?

Can  i use re.search() to validate this? What's the best method?

```
text1 = "AbAb" -> return True 
text2 = "aBaB" -> return True
text3 = "ABaB" -> return False
text4 = "abAb" -> return False
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex. You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/m2Cnc2/1)

```
def check(str_):
    pattern = re.compile("(?:[A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])*")
    return pattern.match(str_).group(0) == str_

check("AbAb")
output: True

check("aBaB")
output: True

check("ABaB")
output: False

check("abAb")
output: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search()`:

```
import re
[*map(lambda x: True if re.search(r'[A-Z][a-z][A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z]', x) else False, 
      [text1, text2, text3, text4])]
```